# Vector of pointers: Why does changing the pointer externally not change the vector element?

Tags: c++, pointers

Please look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Base {
public:
    virtual void price() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void price() const {
        std::cout << "Price of D1\n";
    }
};

class D2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void price() const {
        std::cout << "Price of D2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> v;
    
    
    Base* b = new D1();
    v.push_back(b);
    v[0]->price(); // "Price of D1\n" - OK!
    
    b = new D2();
    v[0]->price(); // "Price of D1\n"?! Why not "Price of D2\n"
}
```

A simple base class has two derived classes. In my `main()` I declare a vector containing pointers to the base class and fill it with a pointer to an object of `D1`.

When I change `b` to a pointer to D2, `b = new D2();`, why doesn't that change the element `v[0]` accordingly? Aren't they supposed to point to the same thing?

Comment: A pointer is a value itself. If you push it to the vector the vector has a copy of this pointer (but not of the pointee). So, you can assign a new value to `b` while its former is still stored in the vector.

Comment: To achieve desired result you should rather modify the pointer that stored in the vector, i.e. `v[0] = new D2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to explain it on a lower level.

First of all, understand that a pointer is essentially simply a variable that holds a value, which happens to be an address in memory.
Let's simplify things and assume that every type has the same size and that there are only 5 addresses of memory (on the heap). (Also I will ignore that the array will allocate on the heap too.)
We now execute

```
Base* b = new D1();
```

Let's say that the allocated memory is at the address 3. `b` is now a variable that simply holds the value 3. Our (heap) memory looks like this:

```
0: ?
1: ?
2: ?
3: variable of type D1
4: ?
```

Then we continue with

```
v.push_back(b);
```

We now have that the array `v` holds one entry of value 3.

```
b = new D2();
```

We now allocated a new part of memory, let's say at address 1:

```
0: ?
1: variable of type D2
2: ?
3: variable of type D1
4: ?
```

`b` now stores this address, that is, the value of b is 1. If we look at `v`, we haven't changed it. It contains one entry with value 3.

```
v[0]->price();
```

This gives us a pointer with value 3, which we dereference and print. Given our memory map above, what is stored there is a variable of type D1.

Did this clarify things for you?

I also extended your code a little bit to demonstrate this with realistic addresses:
http://www.cpp.sh/3s4b4
(If you run that code, note that addresses allocated right after each other tend to be almost similar, often only differing by a single digit, thus look closely. For example, I got 0x1711260 and 0x1711220.)

---

If you really need to do what you expected, you could store a vector over `Base**` and store the address of `b` in the vector:

```
std::vector<Base**> v;

Base* b = new D1();
v.push_back(&b);
(*v[0])->price(); 

b = new D2();
(*v[0])->price();
```

Implemented on http://www.cpp.sh/8c3i3. But I wouldn't recommend that if you don't absolutely need to, lacks readability and unnecessarily confuses. (Note that the first pointer is not deleted in this example and unreachable after changing `b`, thus we'd leak memory.)

Answer (score 3):

> When I change b to a pointer to D2, b = new D2();, why doesn't that change the element v[0] accordingly? Aren't they supposed to point to the same thing?

Because `v.push_back(b);` stores a *copy* of the pointer `b` in your vector. So if you change `b` to point to something else afterwards, it will have no effect whatsoever on `v[0]`

You can simplify it and see it like this:

```
int *ptr = new int;
int *ptr_copy = ptr;

*ptr = 2; //both *ptr and *ptr_copy have value: "2"

ptr = new int; //ptr now points to some other memory
*ptr = 5;      //*ptr = 5, but *ptr_copy will still be "2"
```

Now if you really want the changes to be reflected even when you change the pointer, you need another level of indirection i.e., "pointer to pointer":

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Base**> v; //vector of Base**   
    
    Base* b = new D1();
    v.push_back(&b);
    (*v[0])->price(); // "Price of D1\n" - OK!
    
    b = new D2();
    (*v[0])->price(); // "Price of D2\n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case, then shouldn't I be able to change both pointers by saying, e.g., `*b = d22` where `D2 d22;` in my example? I tried that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, that would normally work but here we are dealing with polymorphism. The memory is initalized with `D1`, so even if you do `*b = d22`, the *type* associated with the memory doesn't change. So it will not work because `b` thinks that it is still pointing to a value of type "D1". (And I am not sure, but in this context this maybe undefined behaviour)

Comment: *b is just a D1, so you're effectively saying D1 = D2, no pointers involved. D1 would use its copy assignment operator to copy values from D2. It would still be the D1 object.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer yes, exactly.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer *b is also the value of v[0], *v[0], so what I don't understand it why *v[0] is left unchanged when changing *b

Comment: @TylerD `v[0]` *is* changed of course. Think of it like this. `int a = 10; float b = 1.;` then `a = b;`. Does it mean now `a` is a float? No. It is still an `int`. Similarly in your case the value is assigned, but the type is still `D1` hence `v[0]->price()` will call `D1`'s `price()`

Comment: @Waqar A follow-up question: What happens if I say `v.push_back(b); delete b;`? Will that also delete the object being pointed by to `v[0]`? My guess is yes because - even though the pointers are copies of each other - they still point to the same thing. Do you agree?

Comment: `delete` will *deallocate* the memory pointed to by `b`. So if `b` and `v[0]` are pointing to the same location (you haven't reasssigned them) then memory will be freed and both will be pointing to inaccessible memory.

Comment: @TylerD a pointer is just a variable like any other. It has an address of it's own, and an address it points to. Any changes to the memory a pointer points to will be reflected to other pointers pointing to that memory location. But a change to the pointer itself (reassignment) will not have any affect on other pointers.

Comment: or b and v[0] could still be pointing to accessible memory, that has been reused for something else, and so effectively contains crap if interpreted as a D1/D2. Bring on the crash / nightmare bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this variation

```
vector<int> v;
int b = 123;
v.push_back(b);
cout << v[0]; // prints 123

b = 456;
cout << v[0]; // still prints 123
```

That changing `b` doesn't change `v[0]` is hopefully obvious, because the value of `v[0]` is a **copy** of the value of `b`. But then compare with your code, what's the difference? There is none, it's exactly the same situation `v[0]` is a copy of `b` and changing `b` doesn't change `v[0]`. The fact that your case involves pointers make no difference at all (in this regard) because *there's nothing special about pointers*.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a pointer into a `std::vector` of pointers, you *copy* that pointer into the container. After

```
std::vector<Base*> v;

Base* b = new D1();
v.push_back(b);
```

you have *two* pointers that refer to the `D1` instance: `b` and `vec[0]`. Now if you go on with

```
b = new D2();
```

you only overwrite *one* of these two, that is obviously `b`, but not `vec[0]`. Hence, accessing `vec[0]` gives you a reference to the pointer stored there in the first place.

Comment: If that is the case, then shouldn't I be able to change both pointers by saying, e.g., `*b = d22` where `D2 d22;`?

Comment: You can change the pointer stored in the container by e.g. `v[0] = b` (given that you have `b = new D2();` beforehand.

Comment: But what happens when I say `*b = d22;` where `D2 d22;`? Why doesn't that change both `band `v[0]`?

Comment: Let's say it changes the instance that these pointers refer to. Thats different from changing a pointer itself. With `*b` you acccess the actual object being pointed at.

Comment: @TylerD `*b = d22` doesn't change either pointer, it changes what both pointers are pointing to, which is a totally different thing. It's the failure to properly distinguish a pointer from what the pointer is pointing to that lies behind most newbie confusions around pointers.